# Does Bishul Yisra'el have to be a "direct" lighting?

Tags: gentiles, bishul-akum

I understand that a Jew needs to light the flame prior to most foods being cooked. Does the lighting need to be "direct"? I.e. does a Jew need to light the flame on the stove or the oven, directly?

Or, may a Jew light a yahrtzeit candle that stays on and can a Gentile take a match and light it from the yahrtzeit candle and use it to light the stove or oven?

Comment: Would your question be applicable to lighting a pilot light from which the oven is lit? " if a non-Jew lit a fire from another fire which was originally ignited by a Jew, there is no restriction of bishul akum. In both of these instances, the fire is considered aish yisrael (fire of a Jew) because of the involvement of the Jew." https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/playing-with-fire/

Comment: @rosends Why not move that as an answer?

Comment: @DanF I didn't know if you were intending to make a distinction between a pilot light and something external to the oven.

Comment: @rosends I hadn't thought about the pilot light at all until you mentioned it. Offhand, I can't see a difference as to whether a Jew lit a pilot light or a yahrtzeit candle.

Comment: If the pilot light is is the oven, it gives off heat, and would make it bishul Yisroel because even a splinter of wood makes it Bishul yisroel. However, if the fire is out of the oven, it does add any heat to the food. It would therefore be a totally different question.

Comment: Based on the title, I thought you were going to ask if remotely igniting a flame (e.g. via a smart home) would satisfy the Ashkenazi requirements for Bishul Yisra'el. Separate question I guess. Shucks.

Answer (score 1):

The Ramah in Shulchan Arch Yoreh Deah 113/7 write that some say it makes it Bishul Yisroel.